# Can't load HttpModule in GAC

Tags: iis, gac, httpmodule

I write a HttpModule in .Net 3.5 and trying to install on the server root of IIS 10 server. I use gacutil.exe v7.0A successfully install it and I use /l command confirm that my module exists. I add configuration below to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config:

```
<add name="ModuleModEF35" type="ModuleModEF35.MyModule, ModuleModEF35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

And I got FileNotFoundException when i browsed the child website. Due to some reasons, I can't place my module in the individual \bin folder though I know it definitely works.

```
namespace ModuleModEF35
{
    class MyModule : System.Web.IHttpModule
    {
        void IHttpModule.Dispose()
        {

        }
        void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += Context_BeginRequest;
        }
        private void Context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            if (context.Request.RawUrl.Contains("%EF"))
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("https://http.cat/403");
                context.Response.End();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the .NET Framework version of that application pool? Note that there are two GACs on the same machine, so if you install to a wrong GAC, the error is expected.

Comment: Application pool use 4.0. And I've checked that the module is in C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL

Comment: Then you installed it just to the wrong place, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac

Comment: I use Developer command prompt VS2015 and type command :"gacutil -if [my dll path]". And I Found my dll is installed in "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL" not in "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL". Not sure if anything wrong.